# How to select multiple images and submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The idea is there are some color swatches in the web page, people can select multiple colors and submit. It's important that we know which color swatches people submitted and who submitted. So far, I have found a solution to select multiple color images (codes as below) but how to submit the selected images with contact form 7? Or other method as long as we can gether the contact info people filled and their selected images.

[photo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjnIT.jpg)

Below is the solution to select multiple images

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

label::before {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

:checked+label {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

:checked+label::before {
  content: "✓";
  background-color: grey;
  transform: scale(1);
}

:checked+label img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
    <label for="cb1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/1/100" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
    <label for="cb2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/2/100" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" />
    <label for="cb3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/3/100" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" />
    <label for="cb4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/4/100" /></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is jQuery version for you. I think it more simplest thing.

```js
$(function() {
    // Multiple images preview in browser
    var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

        if (input.files) {
            var filesAmount = input.files.length;

            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
            }
        }

    };

    $('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add">
<div class="gallery"></div>
```